# Mustache with params in URL

Tags: java, html, spring, mustache

im working on making a web application using mustache and spring, and im trying to show a text, depending on the parameter that is sent through the URL, in this way
"url?category=pwn"

I thought that i could show this the following way:

```
{{#category}}
{{#eq category "pwn"}}
<p>Great, you like pwn!!</p>
{{/eq category "pwn"}}
{{#eq category "rev"}}
<p>Great, you like reversing!!</p>
{{/eq category "rev"}}
{{/category}}
```

but this doesn't work, and I've found nothing, what can i do?